# How to rename rows that have the same value in a column using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have these following dataFrame for a Loan Application:

`df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\exampleLoan.csv")`

```
       Offer ID          Activity       Application ID
 0   Offer_4108    O_Create Offer           App_866651
 1   Offer_4108            O_Sent           App_866651
 2   Offer_4108       O_Cancelled           App_866651
 3   Offer_7743    O_Create Offer           App_691650
 4   Offer_7743         O_Created           App_691650
 5   Offer_7743       O_Cancelled           App_691650
 6   Offer_8595    O_Create Offer           App_691650
 7   Offer_8595            O_Sent           App_691650
 8   Offer_8595       O_Cancelled           App_691650
 9   Offer_8731    O_Create Offer           App_691650
10   Offer_8731            O_Sent           App_691650
11   Offer_8731       O_Cancelled           App_691650
12   Offer_9517    O_Create Offer           App_957884
13   Offer_9517        O_Returned           App_957884
14   Offer_9517         O_Refused           App_957884
15   Offer_9363    O_Create Offer           App_957884
16   Offer_9363        O_Returned           App_957884
17   Offer_9363        O_Accepted           App_957884
```

Every loan application submitted have an ApplicationID. Each Application may have several offers (App_957884 has several offers > Offer_9517 and Offer_9363), each offer must go through a sequence of activities starting with O_Create Offer.

I want to rename O_Create Offer Activity by adding number for each activity with the same ApplicationID but different Offer ID (O_Create Offer1; O_Create Offer2).

Expected Outcome:

```
           Offer ID            Activity       Application ID
     0   Offer_4108    O_Create Offer 1           App_866651
     1   Offer_4108              O_Sent           App_866651
     2   Offer_4108         O_Cancelled           App_866651
     3   Offer_7743    O_Create Offer 1           App_691650
     4   Offer_7743           O_Created           App_691650
     5   Offer_7743         O_Cancelled           App_691650
     6   Offer_8595   O_ Create Offer 2           App_691650
     7   Offer_8595              O_Sent           App_691650
     8   Offer_8595         O_Cancelled           App_691650
     9   Offer_8731    O_Create Offer 3           App_691650
    10   Offer_8731              O_Sent           App_691650
    11   Offer_8731         O_Cancelled           App_691650
    12   Offer_9517    O_Create Offer 1           App_957884
    13   Offer_9517          O_Returned           App_957884
    14   Offer_9517           O_Refused           App_957884
    15   Offer_9363    O_Create Offer 2           App_957884
    16   Offer_9363          O_Returned           App_957884
    17   Offer_9363          O_Accepted           App_957884
```

I'm a beginner with Python, please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing to filter rows (keep only Offer rows) then use [`groupby_cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) to add the expected number:

```
m = df['Activity'].eq('O_Create Offer')
num = ' ' + df[m].groupby('Application ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df.loc[m, 'Activity'] += num
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      Offer ID          Activity Application ID
0   Offer_4108  O_Create Offer 1     App_866651
1   Offer_4108            O_Sent     App_866651
2   Offer_4108       O_Cancelled     App_866651
3   Offer_7743  O_Create Offer 1     App_691650
4   Offer_7743         O_Created     App_691650
5   Offer_7743       O_Cancelled     App_691650
6   Offer_8595  O_Create Offer 2     App_691650
7   Offer_8595            O_Sent     App_691650
8   Offer_8595       O_Cancelled     App_691650
9   Offer_8731  O_Create Offer 3     App_691650
10  Offer_8731            O_Sent     App_691650
11  Offer_8731       O_Cancelled     App_691650
12  Offer_9517  O_Create Offer 1     App_957884
13  Offer_9517        O_Returned     App_957884
14  Offer_9517         O_Refused     App_957884
15  Offer_9363  O_Create Offer 2     App_957884
16  Offer_9363        O_Returned     App_957884
17  Offer_9363        O_Accepted     App_957884
```